# Android Retrieve Image by Intent Uri Failed: "has no access to content..."

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-file, android-storage

I use Intent to pick a photo from gallery:

```
binding.pickPhotoButton.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)

    intent.type = "image/*"

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_PHOTO)
}
```

And save the image uri using `SharedPreferences`:

```
object DataStore {
    fun saveImage(context: Context, imageName: String, imageUri: Uri) {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        sharedPreferences.edit {
            putString(imageName, imageUri.toString())
        }
    }

    fun getImageUri(context: Context, imageName: String): Uri? {
        val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val uriString = sharedPreferences.getString(imageName, "")

        return if (uriString!!.isEmpty()) null else uriString.toUri()
    }
}
```

Saving has no problem, but when I retrieve it and convert to `Bitmap` (to set it with `ImageView`):

```
val inputStream = imageView.context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

inputStream.use {
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it)

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

I got this error: `has no access to content://media/external/images/media/690726`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you decode inputstream in onActivityResult. looks fine.  where do you have    `val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it)`. uris valid for lifetime of your component activity or fragment where you access it

Comment: `uris valid for lifetime of your component activity or fragment where you access it` sounds the point, I got that error when I restart the app. So that means I have to create a copy of the image file into somewhere, then I can retrieve it, right?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html. I guess you need to get the uri by picking the image again or create a local copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, searched and experimented a lot, here is the solution:

**Just use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, that's enough. No need `takePersistableUriPermission()`.**

---

One more interesting finding: `takePersistableUriPermission()` doesn't work for `Intent.ACTION_PICK` **and** `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Which is too bad, because `ACTION_PICK` lanuches the gallery app, provides a better ui look, while `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` launches the native file explorer app.

Answer (score 1):

The read permission for the uri has gone after restart of your app or if you use the uri in another activity.

But there is a solution.

Instead of ACTION_PICK use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and take persistable uri permission for the obtained uri in onActivityResult().

Comment: Thanks a lot. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` did the work. No need `takePersistableUriPermission()`.